# Water shut off to solder on an adapter?

Tags: plumbing, solder

I need to put an adapter onto a ball valve at the end of a supply line.  Do I need to shut the water off to the whole line?

Comment: Does it required soldering?

Comment: Yea....attaching the adapter to go to the new bathroom.  Going from copper to pex

Comment: The pipe were you are soldering can't have water in it as it will absorb the heat and prevent a good (or any) connection. As long as your section of pipe is water free then you are good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ball valve can, I assume, shut off the flow where you need to attach the adapter. In that case just close the valve, attach your adapter, and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

There are other options, one is to get a “pipefreezer”, a kit that freezes a section of pipe allowing you to work on the free end.